# Prove that the maximum area of a rectangle inscribed in an ellipse is $2ab$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, conic-sections, area, maxima-minima

> Prove that the maximum area of a rectangle inscribed in an ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is $2ab$.

**My attempt:**

Equation of ellipse: $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.

Assume that $a>b$ & let $l$ & $w$ are length and width of rectangle then area will be $$A=l\times w \tag{1}$$

Now, I substituted the point $\left(\dfrac {l}{2}, \dfrac {w}{2}\right)$ in the equation of ellipse
$$\frac{(l/2)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(w/2)^2}{b^2}=1,$$
$$b^2l^2+a^2w^2=4a^2b^2.\tag{2}$$

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: How do you know that the rectangle must have sides parallel to the major and the minor axes of the ellipse?  While this is indeed the case that the sides are indeed parallel to the axes, this result is far from being obvious.  $$\phantom{a}$$  That being said, there are multiple ways to go: using the AM-GM Inequality, parametrizing the points on the ellipse with $\sin$ and $\cos$, differentiation, or rewrite the optimization problem in terms of a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The area of a square inscribed in a circle is $2r^2$

Comment: @Batominovski: Good lord how did you get a paragraph break into your comment?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC  I cheated.  I used `$$\phantom{a}$$`.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the coordinate transformation $$(u,v) = (x/a, y/b),$$ which maps the ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$ to the unit circle $$u^2 + v^2 = 1.$$  Such a transformation preserves the ratios of areas; in particular, if a quadrilateral inscribed in the ellipse has maximal area among all such quadrilaterals, then the transformed quadrilateral under this mapping will also have maximal area; and vice versa.  This is not difficult to show.

Therefore, it suffices to consider all quadrilaterals inscribed in the unit circle in the transformed coordinate system.  Since we know that the quadrilateral of maximal area in a circle is a square (proof below), it follows that the family of quadrilaterals of maximal area inscribed in the ellipse are those parallelograms that arise from the inverse transformation.  These squares all have diagonal with length $2$, thus area of $2$, and upon the inverse transformation, the corresponding parallelograms all have area $2ab$.  Of these, there is only one that is a rectangle, corresponding to the configuration where the sides are parallel to the coordinate axes; although merely observing existence is sufficient (uniqueness is irrelevant).

---

For the proof that a quadrilateral of maximal area inscribed in a circle is a square, let $ABCD$ be any quadrilateral inscribed in the circle.  Consider a diagonal, say $AC$.  Then $\triangle ABC$ is an inscribed triangle whose area is maximized when the height $h_B$ perpendicular to $AC$ is maximized, since $AC$ is fixed.  This corresponds to choosing the midpoint of $AC$ as the foot of the perpendicular.  Similarly, the area of $\triangle ADC$ is maximized in the same manner.  But this means $BD$ must be a diameter, since the feet of the perpendiculars coincide, both being the midpoint of $AC$, and the perpendicular to any chord through its midpoint is a diameter.  Thus among all quadrilaterals with fixed diagonal $AC$, the one that maximizes the area is one where the other diagonal $BD$ is a diameter.  Then among all such quadrilaterals with $BD$ as diameter, the one that maximizes the area is the one where $AC$ is also a diameter.  Since $AC \perp BD$, it follows $ABCD$ is a square.

Comment: I figured there would be something like this when I commented (above) about the area of a square inscribed in a circle

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier method to prove (without using Calculus).

The sides (i.e. length and width) of inscribed rectangle have to be parallel to the axes of ellipse to make all four vertices of inscribed rectangle lie on the ellipse.

Consider $(\pm a\cos\theta, \pm b\sin\theta)$ as four vertices of inscribed rectangle lying on the ellipse: $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

Then the area of inscribed rectangle will be $A=(2a\cos\theta)(2b\sin\theta)=2ab\sin2\theta$

Now, the area $2ab\sin2\theta$  will be maximum when $\color{red}{\sin2\theta}$ is maximum i.e. $\color{red}{1}$

Therefore the maximum area of rectangle inscribed in an ellipse is $\color{blue}{2ab}$

Comment: You have made a big assumption --- why must the sides of the rectangle be parallel to the axes?

Comment: @user10354138: Probably OP has made that big assumption to get max area $2ab$

Comment: No.  See heropup's answer which does not make that assumption; or prove directly that maximum area must occur when the rectangle is symmetric about $O$, i.e., $\pm(a\cos\psi,b\sin\psi), \pm(a\cos\phi,b\sin\phi)$ and impose orthognality to get a relation between $\phi$ and $\psi$, hence maximize the area.

Comment: Well for your understanding if the sides of a quadrilateral inscribed in an ellipse are not parallel to the axes then it can't be a rectangle however it may be a parallelogram (no interior angle is $90^\circ$). So a quadrilateral inscribed in an ellipse will be a rectangle iff its sides are parallel to the axes. Isn't it true?

Comment: @user10354138: Can you draw an inscribed rectangle whose sides are not parallel to the axes of ellipse such that all its vertices lie on the ellipse? You can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You need to *prove* this, not just assert it.  See my previous comment.

Comment: Well, OP has asked to prove the maximum area but not to prove that the sides of inscribed rectangle are parallel to axes of ellipse. The answer needn't be rigorous.

Comment: One counterexample is when the ellipse is a circle ($a=b$). Then the sides can be nonparallel to axes.

Comment: You are right but this is not the case of circle. It is clearly the case of a rectangle inscribed in an ellipse. That's why the sides of rectangle have to be parallel to the axes of ellipse there is no way out

Answer (score -1):

Let one vertex of the rectangle be $(a\cos t, b\sin t)$. Then, the other three are known as well and the area is

$$A= 4ab|\sin t \cos t |\le 2ab (\cos^2t+\sin^2t)=2ab$$

where the inequality $2uv\le u^2+v^2 $ is used.

Comment: You have made a big assumption --- why must the sides of the rectangle be parallel to the axes?

Comment: +1 just to neutralize down vote